# How to display three rows within a table row, not three colums

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an application [here](http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0867587/Mobile_app/QandATable3.php) for you to be able to see the layout of a problem I am having. When you open the application, if you click on the "Add Question" button, you will see that it displays a table row with three columns showing the content.

The first column shows Options textbox, second is a number textbox and third is 2 buttons. The problem is that it is displaying three columns in row going side by side.

It should be instead be showing within the table row, three rows, not three columns.

So currently it is showing this for each table row:

```
Option Textbox | Number Textbox | 2 Buttons
```

Instead it should be inside a table row:

```
Option Textbox

Number Textbox

2 Buttons
```

So like I said, I need three rows within the row, not three columns. But how can i achieve this with the code I have below:

```
var $tbody = $('#qandatbl > tbody'); 
            var $tr = $("<tr class='optionAndAnswer' align='center'></tr>");
            var $noofanswers = $("<tr><td class='noofanswers'></td></tr>");
            var $options = $("<tr><td class='option'></td></tr>");
            var $answer = $("<tr><td class='answer'></td></tr>");
            var $extratr = $("<tr></tr>");

        /*Below is an example of a function that worked before I included the <tr> tag
 but stopped working after including the <tr> tags */

      $('.numberAnswerTxt', context).each(function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            var $noofanswersText = '';

            if ($questionType == 'True or False' || $questionType == 'Yes or No'){

        $noofanswersText = $("<span class='naRow string' style='display: block;'>Only 1 Answer</span><input type='text' class='numberAnswerTxtRow answertxt' style='display: none;' onkeyup='numberKeyUp(this)' onkeypress='return isNumberKey(event)' onChange='getButtons()'>").attr('name', $this.attr('name')).attr('value', $this.val());

        }else{

        $noofanswersText = $("<span class='naRow string' style='display: none;'>Only 1 Answer</span><input type='text' class='numberAnswerTxtRow answertxt' style='display: block;' onkeyup='numberKeyUp(this)' onkeypress='return isNumberKey(event)' onChange='getButtons()'>").attr('name', $this.attr('name')).attr('value', $this.val());  

        }

            $noofanswers.append($noofanswersText);

            }); 

            $tr.append($extratr);
            $extratr.append($options);
            $extratr.append($noofanswers);
            $extratr.append($answer);
            $tbody.append($tr);
```

Comment: To end a row, use </tr>. To begin a row, use <tr>. So, append($tr) after each <td>.

Comment: Just wrap each `td` with a `tr`.

Comment: @DavidThomas Now this is the problem because I tried this method before you told me, if I do this then the functions associated with those td's do not work. I will update code to show an example of a function that did work before inserting the tr but stopped working after inserting the tr's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A table row is denoted by an opening and closing `tr` so you need to make this change:

```
var $noofanswers = $("<tr><td class='noofanswers'></td></tr>");
var $options = $("<tr><td class='option'></td></tr>");
var $answer = $("<tr><td class='answer'></td></tr>");
```

each of those will create a row in your table.

Comment: Thanks, but that is now a completely different question!

Comment: I tried this theory before I posted this question. that was the problem I got so I wondered if there was another way of displaying three rows so that functions can also work correctly

Comment: Your code isn't complete. There is no element with class `numberAnswerTxt` so it would be impossible to troubleshoot.

Comment: You will need to change your logic to search over the three rows instead of three columns.. I'd suggest you create a jsfiddle with all the appropriate code to better help you.  In all fairness, I answered your original question along with many other comments.  This should be a completely separate question.

Comment: go on then, I will mark it and ask a seperate question, even though I already this before posting this question.

Answer (score 0):

Why not put a table within the cell and give it three rows, or try useing the rowspan attribute with the other cells so that the span 3 rows.